# Запросы SQL сумирование одинаковых значений

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть таблица Order как можно посчитать количество одинаковых OrderDate данных

```
O_Id    OrderDate   OrderPrice  Customer
1       2008/11/12  1000            Hansen
2       2008/11/12  1600            Nilsen
3       2008/09/02  700             Hansen
4       2008/09/03  300             Hansen
5       2008/09/03  2000            Jensen
6       2008/09/03  100             Nilsen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select `OrderDate`,count(*) as `Amount` from `Order` group by `OrderDate`
```

это количество.

```
select `OrderDate`,count(`OrderPrice`) as `Amount` from `Order` group by `OrderDate`
```

это цена в эту дату.

Comment: А что значит Amount

Comment: это алиас, псевдоним, как вам удобнее для count(*) в первом случае, во втором  для count(`OrderPrice`)

Comment: @nolka+1.
Это так будет называться столбец в полученной таблице.
В вашем примере для первого случая:

    OrderDate|Amount
    2008/11/12|2
    2008/09/02|1
    2008/09/03|3

Для второго:

    OrderDate|Amount
    2008/11/12|2600
    2008/09/02|700
    2008/09/03|2400

Слово "as" можно иногда опускать. Но я никогда не помнил когда, поэтому пишу каждый раз.